# Copy Wizard errors out with Timeout Expired

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to copy a 2008 r2 database to an SQL 2012 server. I am using the same users and proxies that I have in the past that worked ok.  This database however is larger than the others and when it runs it fails with a timeout expire on creating the name.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier and faster to:

1. Detach the database From 2008
2. Attach it to 2012
3. Change compatibility level to 110
4. Update statistics
5. Clear plan cache

Step 1 and 2 can be replaced by a backup of 2008 and restore on 2012

Comment: I thought about that but I have been told that the logins aren't always transferred.